# Finding the name of a camera

Tags: ros-kinetic, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to run the following ros command:

```
rosrun ros_flydra camhistograms --camera /Basler_XXX/image_raw
```

Where in the documentation for flydra, Basler_XXX is supposed to be replaced with the name of the camera you are using. I'm having trouble finding the name of my camera, and am confused if it is named by ros or by the flydra program.

When I run 'lsusb' I get the following

```
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 002 Device 007: ID 1e10:3300 Point Grey Research, Inc. 

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1e10:3300 Point Grey Research, Inc. 

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c537 Logitech, Inc. 

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Where the two point grey cameras are the cameras I'm using.

In an example command a few lines down in the documentation:

```
rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 6x8 --square=0.029 image:=/Basler_21020232/image_raw camera:=Basler_21020232
```

Which makes me think that the name I need is simply "Manufacturer_Serial" because the serial number is the same digits as his example when I run the command:

```
rosrun pointgrey_camera_driver list_cameras

Number of cameras found: 2

[0]Serial: 18467619, Model: Flea3 FL3-U3-13E4M, Vendor: Point Grey Research, Sensor: E2v EV76C560 (1/1.8" Mono CMOS), Resolution: 1280x1024, Color: false, Firmware Version: 2.15.3.3

[1]Serial: 18467624, Model: Flea3 FL3-U3-13E4M, Vendor: Point Grey Research, Sensor: E2v EV76C560 (1/1.8" Mono CMOS), Resolution: 1280x1024, Color: false, Firmware Version: 2.15.3.3
```

How can I find out the name needed for the command? Any suggestions are appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324276/finding-the-name-of-a-camera/) by [mbfg](https://answers.ros.org/users/41813/mbfg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2019-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What it is looking for is the name space of the `image_raw` topic to get images from. This is determined by whatever is launching your camera nodes.

*If you already have camera nodes running:*

The easiest way to get this is to start your camera nodes and run `rostopic list`. This will list the topics on your system, so just look for `image_raw` topics coming from your cameras. That will let you know what the fully-qualified topic name is, which is what you pass to the `camhistograms` node. If you want to check which topic is which camera, use the [image_view](http://wiki.ros.org/image_view) package to display the image from the cameras, one at a time, and wave your hand in front of each camera to identify it.

*If you do not already have camera nodes running:*

You will need to start the nodes for your cameras. According to the [`pointgrey_camera_driver` documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/pointgrey_camera_driver), you should pass the serial number of the camera (which you have already found) in as the `camera_serial` argument for `roslaunch`. (I took a quick look at the code and it looks like it will try to find the serial number itself if you do not provide it.) However this is just for providing camera information. The node name and thus the name space the `image_raw` topic lives under has a default defined in the `camera.launch` file, but you can override that by passing the `camera_name` argument to `roslaunch`. Since you have two cameras, you will probably need to do this. The wonderful thing here is that you can define what each camera is called, so you know exactly what to pass to `ros_flydra/camhistograms`. If you name your cameras `bob` and `bill`, then the topics will be `/bob/image_raw` and `/bill/image_raw`.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2019-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mbfg](https://answers.ros.org/users/41813/mbfg/) on 2019-05-30**:
Thanks for formatting my post so it is pretty, and thanks for the answer.